# SIMD reordering permute algorithm

Tags: algorithms, sorting

The question is about how to schedule the pairwise SIMD instruction to move the data in proper position.

Say I n SIMD registers, each SIMD register contains n elements.

If each **column** represent a SIMD register.

They forms a matrix:

\begin{pmatrix}
a_0 & a_1 & a_2 & a_3 \\
b_0 & b_1 & b_2 & b_3 \\
c_0 & c_1 & c_2 & c_3 \\
d_0 & d_1 & d_2 & d_3 \\
\end{pmatrix}

element *a_0* is held by *SIMD register 0* 's first position.

*SIMD register 0* holds <a0, b0, c0, d0>

Now the data initialized in the matrix like below.

\begin{pmatrix}
a_0 & a_1 & a_2 & a_3 \\
b_3 & b_0 & b_1 & b_2 \\
c_2 & c_3 & c_0 & c_1 \\
d_1 & d_2 & d_3 & d_0 \\
\end{pmatrix}

Each **column** still represent a SIMD regsiter.
Except r0 has <a0, b3, c2, d1>.

How can I transform it back using pairwise SIMD masked register element exchange instruction, using as less instruction as possible? (with a general algorithm to deal with any n)

That's is to way I want to make r0 holds <a0, b0, c0, d0> as before.

Using an example to explain exchange instruction:

r0 :  <a,b,c>

r1 :  <e,d,f>

In one instruction *e* can switch with *a*, similar *b* and *d*, *c* and *f*, but not *a* and *d* or *b* and *c*.

Comment: This question may be too specific to an ISA; generating good code for SSE may be different from Neon. Nonetheless, this may help: https://users.ece.cmu.edu/~franzf/papers/cc08.pdf

Comment: @Pseudonym I think this is a rather general question in any SIMD architecture machine. GPU can somehow be model in this way as well. The only difference is the size of N and how efficient they can access a global memory (so that you don't need such exchange algorithm).